# Rails 6 & route for custom post- action for nested resource & form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, nested-routes

I need to make a separate create action for the nested Answer resource, such as *create_xhr*, which will be called in the form on the parent resource.
This is what the route for the Answer resource looks like:

```rb
  namespace :admin do
    resources :tests do
      resources :questions, shallow: true, except: %i[index] do
        resources :answers, shallow: true, except: %i[index]
      end
    end
  end
```

The path should look something like this:

```
post '/questions/:question_id/answers/create_xhr
```

So that in the Answers controller, the new object is associated with the current Question.
Now I've come to an option:

```rb
  namespace :admin do
    resources :tests do
      resources :questions, shallow: true, except: %i[index] do
        resources :answers, shallow: true, except: %i[index] do
          post :create_xhr, on: :new
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

I get the route:

```
create_xhr_new_admin_question_answer POST   /admin/questions/:question_id/answers/new/create_xhr(.:format)  admin/answers#create_xhr
```

And then I create a form on the show page for Question:

```rb
<%= form_with url: create_xhr_new_admin_question_answer_path(@question), local: false do |form| %>
```

But the parameters of the new Answer do not come inside the **"answer"** key:

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "body"=>"text", "correct"=>"false", "commit"=>"Add answer", "lang"=>"en", "question_id"=>"7"}
```

It must be:

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "answer"=>{"body"=>"text", "correct"=>"false"}, "commit"=>"Add answer", "lang"=>"en", "question_id"=>"7"}
```

If I specify a model in the form instead of a URL, then rails selects the default action **create**.

I also tried writing the route directly in the Admin namespace block:

```
post '/questions/:question_id/answers/create_xhr', to: 'answers#create_xhr', as: :create_answer_on_question
```

and get a route:

```
admin_create_answer_on_question POST   /admin/questions/:question_id/answers/create_xhr(.:format)   admin/answers#create_xhr
```

However, the problem with the parameters coming to the controller is the same.

Where am I wrong?
Should I write the router or the form differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, in the form you must specify both the model and the path.
In the end, it all looks like this:

```rb
  namespace :admin do
    resources :tests do
      resources :questions, shallow: true, except: %i[index] do
        resources :answers, shallow: true, except: %i[index]
      end
    end
    
    post '/questions/:question_id/answers/create_xhr', to: 'answers#create_xhr', as: :create_answer_on_question
  end
```

and form:

```rb
<%= form_with model: [:admin, @question, @question.answers.new ], url: admin_create_answer_on_question_path(@question), local: false do |form| %>
```

Then Answer parameters come nested in the controller.

Inside the **resources :answer**s block, I couldn't find a way to normally spell the action without new in the path.